# Bluetooth scanning not worked in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am using core bluetooth central manager and peripheral functionality for one of my application. In which i want to find near by devices based on the bluetooth. So my single class handles all the peripheral as well as central manager code.  It works fine when user in the foreground.

Suppose user A and B using my application. So in the nearby devices tab, Device A can see the device B and vice versa. But when user A enters in the background then it automatically disappears from device B list i.e stop acting as peripheral.

I have already added bluetooth keys in the background mode i.e. (App communicates using CoreBluetooth and App shares data using CoreBluetooth)  but still bluetooth scanning does not work in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Device A must scan with specific service uuid of device B.

```
[centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_UUID]] options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
```

Comment: Where to trigger this code from, if the app is already in the background?
For example, if I have to scan for BLE everyday at 11AM and my app is in background at that time, how should I do this scanning?